# How to keep selected tab on PostBack or call beforeActivate method programmally

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs

I've created a custom control on c# to have several tabs with different forms.
I have two views: preview view (where all inputs are disabled) and an edit view.
I can navigate through the tabs easily but when I click on the edit button,it triggers a PostBack an then the selected tab returns to the first tab available.

Is it possible to keep the selected tab on postback?

**C# code:**

```
public string GetStartupScript()
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.AppendFormat("$(\"#{0}\")", this.ClientID);
    str.Append(".tabs({ beforeActivate: function(e,ui) {");
    str.Append(CustomJSInSelectedTab);
    str.Append(GetSetSelectedTabIndexScript());
    str.Append("}");
    str.Append("}");
    return str.ToString();
}

public string GetSetSelectedTabIndexScript()
{
        StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
           script.AppendFormat("SelectTab(ui.newPanel,'{0}');", _hdnSelectedTabId.ClientID);

        return script.ToString();
}
```

**Javascript code:**

```
SelectTab = function (newpanel, hdnIndexId) {
    $("#" + hdnIndexId).val($(newpanel.selector)[0].id);
}
```

When I click on other tab it calls the beforeActivate method which does the trick. Can I programmally call that function? Or this is a hardcoded work around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already track the selected tab on a hidden field, all you have to do is to add "active" on your code, like this:

```
active: <%= hdnSelectedTab.Value %>
```

Give me feedback if you solve it.

Comment: Didn't know I could use it on my javascript! millions thanks!